# Use of @Query method with @Scheduled process

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

**Explanations:**

I would like to use the annotation `@Query` with `@Scheduled` together but I didn't find a way to do it.

The issue is that you need to be authenticated to use `@Query` to be able to use the current session in the query. But in a method run with `@Scheduled`, there is no authentication. Here is an example of a stack trace to show the issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:61)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1.<init>(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:463)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.toAdapters(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.access$000(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$ExtensionAwarePropertyAccessor.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.StringN1qlBasedQuery.parseSpel(StringN1qlBasedQuery.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.StringN1qlBasedQuery.getStatement(StringN1qlBasedQuery.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:94)
...
```

This mechanism is automatically configured in Spring Boot with `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityDataConfiguration` in order to be able to query data for the authenticated user (via SpEL).

**What I use:**

- Spring Boot v1.5.7.RELEASE
- Spring Boot Auto configuration with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

**What I want:**

I don't want my `@Query` methods to be able to use the `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` provided by Spring Boot because I don't use it in my project (no entity is linked to the connected user).

For that, I want to disable the `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` auto-configured in `SecurityDataConfiguration`.

**What I tried:**

- redefine the bean `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` in a custom Configuration class to return a `null` bean (instead of `new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension()`) but I am not allowed to do it.
- exclude configuration `SecurityDataConfiguration` but it is not defined as auto-configuration, it's included inside the class `SecurityAutoConfiguration`:

  - I am not sure I can exclude only `SecurityDataConfiguration` as it is not an AutoConfiguration class.
  - I am not sure it is a good idea to exclude all this `SecurityAutoConfiguration` class from the auto configuration (as it also includes other security configuration).

Comment: See https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-invoking-a-secured-method-from-a-scheduled-job/.